# Why do Predators only hunt Aliens on Earth every 100 years?

Tags: plot-explanation, aliens-vs-predator

Per *Alien vs. Predator*'s story Predators have come to Earth every 100 years to hunt Aliens from the ancient times.

My question is, why do Predators only hunt every 100 years?

Is it because of traveling time from the Predators' planet to Earth taking 100 years or is there any reason mentioned in the movie?

Comment: I'm guessing it's just tradition to do it every 100 years, like how we hold the Olympics every four years.

Comment: The hunt they do every 100 years is a rite of passage, it's not just a normal hunt. The ancient predators are 1000 years old, so you can see how 100 years would be nothing to them. Their ships are capable of interstellar travel, so it doesn't take 100 years to travel that distance.

Comment: 100's the key number here. Think about it. 100 cents. 100 on your paper. 100, man, that's the number! 100 marmosets typin' in a chat, eatin' lots of curios in my stepdad's flat. You know that old children's tale from the sea! It's like...you're dreamin' about Soppressata sausage when it's clearly Pancetta time, baby! Step into my office.

Comment: It strongly implied that the Predator species uses base 10.  As I don't think time/space is an issue re: travel, it may have to do with humans presumably not the only species that are hunted.  (My real question is who would win between the blue monsters populating the Avatar planet vs. the Predators?)

Comment: @JasonPSallinger - is your comment a reference?  I am thinking of something Christopher Walken would say...

Comment: @m1gp0z Harland Williams diatribe to Ben Stiller in Something About Mary.  The scene where Stiller picks up a hitchhiker.  The form is the same, all of the nouns are ad libbed.

Comment: @JasonPSallinger - Ah, great reference! I remember now